# How to put Json data in a variable Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

[image]

In the `params.value`, I have 3 arrays, of which I need to put the Names in a variable. I try to do through `ForEach` but I can not do it, what's wrong?

```
var roles = params.forEach(x => params.value.Name);
return roles;

{"Object":[{"TerritoryId":1,"TerritoryName":"Russia","FirmPieRotationRuleId":1,"FirmPieWorkedYears":0,"FirmPieCoolOff":5,"FirmPieRoles":[{"TeamRoleId":1,"Name":"Engagement Leader","MinCount":1,"MaxCount":1,"SortOrder":0},{"TeamRoleId":2,"Name":"Signing Partner","MinCount":1,"MaxCount":1,"SortOrder":0},{"TeamRoleId":3,"Name":"Engagement Manager","MinCount":1,"MaxCount":1,"SortOrder":0}],"StatutoryPieRotationRuleId":null,"StatutoryPieWorkedYears":null,"StatutoryPieCoolOff":null,"StatutoryPieRoles":[],"NonPieRotationRuleId":null,"NonPieWorkedYears":null,"NonPieCoolOff":null,"NonPieRoles":[]}],"Code":0,"ErrorMessage":null,"Errors":[]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array#forEach` doesn't return anything. Try `Array#map` instead.

```
var roles = params.map(x => params.value.Name);
```

Comment: I have error "params.map is not a function" Although I used "import 'rxjs/Rx';"

Comment: @ValitskiyDmitriy `params` variable comes from asynchro request?

Comment: No, There is no request as such. This is a table, and it works with a response from the server. For the right speakers, it takes the parts you need

Comment: {
                        headerName: "Roles",
                        field: "FirmPieRoles",
                        editable: true,
                        cellEditorFramework: DropdownEditorComponent,
                        cellEditorParams: {
                            values: RolesDictionary
                        },
                        cellRenderer: function (params) {
                            var roles = params.map(x => params.value.Name);
                            return roles;
                        }
                    },

Comment: @ValitskiyDmitriy Is it Angular? Anyways, what argument you are passing to the `cellRenderer` function?

Comment: Yes, Angular 2.  I use Ag-Grid component. CellRender Function for drawing tables

Comment: @ValitskiyDmitriy You should have mentioned it in your post. Show the `params` variable, please.

Comment: The request or its contents?

Comment: {"Object":[{"TerritoryId":1,"TerritoryName":"Russia","FirmPieRotationRuleId":1,"FirmPieWorkedYears":0,"FirmPieCoolOff":5,"FirmPieRoles":[{"TeamRoleId":1,"Name":"Engagement Leader","MinCount":1,"MaxCount":1,"SortOrder":0},{"TeamRoleId":2,"Name":"Signing Partner","MinCount":1,"MaxCount":1,"SortOrder":0},{"TeamRoleId":3,"Name":"Engagement Manager","MinCount":1,"MaxCount":1,"SortOrder":0}],"StatutoryPieRotationRuleId":null,"StatutoryPieWorkedYears":null,"StatutoryPieCoolOff":null,"StatutoryPieRoles":

Comment: [],"NonPieRotationRuleId":null,"NonPieWorkedYears":null,"NonPieCoolOff":null,"NonPieRoles":[]}],"Code":0,"ErrorMessage":null,"Errors":[]}

Comment: @ValitskiyDmitriy It's JSON object, you can't use `Array#map` on it.

Comment: array#ForEach Still not the same?

Comment: @ValitskiyDmitriy These functions are `Array` prototype functions.

Comment: Hmm, and that  can try on foreach?

Comment: @ValitskiyDmitriy Please edit you question and post **readable** `params` variable :)

Comment: @ValitskiyDmitriy Try `params.Object[0].FirmPieRoles.map(v => v.Name)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `value` is the array. Try this:

```
var roles = params.value.map(val => val.Name)
```